# Resolve overlapping elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

My HTML page has a header, navigation bar, body content element and a footer element however the footer element is overlapping with the div element bodycontent when it should be below the bodycontent element and at the bottom of the page. Please suggest any changes in positioning to resolve this.

```
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    color: #424242;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}
.footer {
    clear: both;
    position: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #808080;
    color:#fff;
}
.prodheading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav_bar{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px; margin-left: -200px;
  padding: 0px;

 list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

}
.bodycontent{
    position:relative;
    top:45px;
    bottom:30px
    padding:15px;
}
```

My home HTML page -

```
<html>
<head>
<style><%@include file="/css/mystyle.css"%></style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> 
<div class="bodycontent">
<h3>Our Mission</h3>
<p>Hello World !!!</p>
<h3></h3>
<p>Trying out webpage</p>
</div>
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

The header html element -

```
<html>

<head>
<style><%@include file="/css/mystyle.css"%></style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<h5>Title 2</h5>

</center>


  <ul class="nav_bar">
    <li class="navit"><a class="link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navit"><a class="link" >Items</a></li>
    <li class="navit"><a class="link" >About Us</a></li>
    <li class="navit"><a class="link" >Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The footer html element

```
<html>
<head>
<style><%@include file="/css/mystyle.css"%></style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>All rights reserved 2018</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey dfvc! Thanks for contributing to SO! Could you please post any relevant HTML for this question as well? It's hard to troubleshoot code when we can't see a "final" product of any kind! Thanks in advanced

Comment: @Ryan Hi, I have updated the HTML elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add CSS code like this:

```css
.header {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    color: #424242;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}
.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #808080;
    color:#fff;
}
.prodheading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav_bar{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px; margin-left: -200px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;

}
.bodycontent{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding:15px;
}
```

Now, You can add CSS for main menu design in `ul.nav_bar` as per your requirements.